# How to add php file on wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to include a php file in a page using wordpress.
However, everything didn't work.

I found something interesting, but it doesn't work and I'm wondering if you can help me.

Basically, I'm trying to make a plugin to add php file in a page.

```html
<?php



// include PHP file
function PHP_Include($params = array()) {

 extract(shortcode_atts(array(
     'file' => 'default'
 ), $params));
 
 ob_start();
 include(get_theme_root() . '/' . get_template() . '/folder' . "/$file.php");
 return ob_get_clean();
}


// register shortcode
add_shortcode('phpinclude', 'PHP_Include');

?>
```

I don't know how to add php code here, sorry.

I type [phpinclude file='namefile'] in my page.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin maybe??

Comment: I was reading, but I'm not sure to understand.

The code above seems to be not so complicated for nothing, but something doesn't work and I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I did that and it works.

However, I don’t know if the code is fine and save.

```html
// include PHP file
function PHP_Include( $atts )
{
 
     extract(shortcode_atts( array(
        'file' => 'default'
     ), $atts ));
 
 
 include get_theme_root() . '/' . get_template() . '/chart/' . $file;
 
}

// register shortcode
add_shortcode('phpinclude', 'PHP_Include');

?>
```